# How should I work with sync I/o?

Tags: sound-design, pro-tools, software

I have one 192 io and a sync I/o . But when I hook up my sync l/o to hd core card . It doesn't work . I don't know wht the problem is. Is it the cable? Or do I need to do anything special on my protools?